# How to use python threadpool to execute none static function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, threadpool, python-multithreading

I'm new on multithreading. I have went through a few document online. I notice examples are using static function as Threadpool input. such as,

```
def task(n):
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Processing {}".format(n))

def main():

    print("Starting ThreadPoolExecutor")
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:

        future = executor.submit(task,(2))
        future = executor.submit(task,(3))
        future = executor.submit(task,(4))
        future = executor.submit(task,(5))
        future = executor.submit(task,(6))
        future = executor.submit(task,(7))
        future = executor.submit(task,(8))
        future = executor.submit(task,(9))
        future = executor.submit(task,(10))
```

Above sample runs well. task executed parallelly

However, if I'm using function from instance like this

```
    class Test():
        def __init__(self, nums):
            self.nums = nums

        def test(self):

            print("Processing {}".format(str(self.nums)))
            time.sleep(3)

    def main():
        future = executor.submit(Test(2).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(3).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(4).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(5).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(6).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(7).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(8).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(9).test())
        future = executor.submit(Test(10).test())
```

The execution is sequential, it will execute first sleep 3 seconds, and then execute the second. It does not run parallelly anymore.

I have tried ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor, Pool, all of them perform the same, function from class instance does not execute parallelly.

In Java, we can executor a Runnable with Threadpool, like this

```
Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);  
executor.execute(worker);
```

Does Python have the similar API perform the same? or use on-static function?

Comment: As a side note: `(2)` is not a tuple of one value, it's just the number `2` inside unnecessary parentheses. If you actually want to pass a tuple of one value, you have to write `(2,)`. Fortunately, you _don't_ want to pass a tuple here—`submit` just takes 0 or more arguments to pass to the function.

Comment: Also, your Java example (assuming that `WorkerThread` isn't a badly misleading name) is using a thread pool to create a bunch of new independent threads, which is a waste of a thread pool. You want to put _tasks_ (aka `Runnable`s), not threads, on a thread pool. Just like in Python, except in Python you can just pass any callable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your two examples:

```
    future = executor.submit(task,(2))
    future = executor.submit(Test(2).test())
```

The first one is passing a function and argument.

The second one is calling a method and passing the result.

What you want is to do is pass the method:

```
    future = executor.submit(Test(2).test)
```